# Setting up a new wordpress site without taking the old site offline

Tags: wordpress

So I am going to setup an new site for a client, and normally I completly remove the DB + wordpress core and install a new wordpress version but I know this is not the best and fastest way to do this.

So how to setup a new wordpress site when the exiting site cant be taken down(prevent long downtime).

Comment: Are you going to replace old website with completely new website ? or some modification ?

Comment: I have build a new site, so I need to remove the old site after

Comment: Just point to a new domain name and different wordpress directory in the server and different DB_NAME(if both sites are on the same server)

Comment: If you can modify virtual hosts, upload the new website to a path that is different to the current one, import the database, update the base URLs, and make that path the document root.

Answer (score 0):

Steps -
1. Make a zip of your new website, upload to server.
2. Now install your DB to new server and give table name prefix different than old one, suppose previous installation table prefix was `wp_`, new installation prefix should be `wpn_` or anything relevant to your site.

3. Still your website there, now move all your old existing site file to a folder.
4. Extract your uploaded zip(new code) to main directory.
5. Check Database connection once and you are done !